# Tensorflow-Lite unresolved reference for tfLite!!.setUseNNAPI in kotlin Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run [this app](https://github.com/lmoroney/dlaicourse/tree/master/TensorFlow%20Deployment/Course%202%20-%20TensorFlow%20Lite/Week%202/Examples/Android%20Apps/object_detection) which is an object detection application. The app uses Tensorflow-Lite.

When trying to run this app I get the error

```
Unresolved reference: setUseNNAPI
```

for these lines

```
override fun setUseNNAPI(isChecked: Boolean) {
    if (tfLite != null) tfLite!!.setUseNNAPI(isChecked)
}
```

It cannot find a reference for `tfLite!!.setUseNNAPI(isChecked)`. This function should somehow be connected to the `Interpreter` options but these are set in the `create` method:

```
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun create(
            assetManager: AssetManager,
            modelFilename: String,
            labelFilename: String,
            inputSize: Int,
            isQuantized: Boolean): Classifier {
        ...

        try {
            val options = Interpreter.Options()
            options.setNumThreads(4)
            options.setUseNNAPI(false)
            d.tfLite = Interpreter(loadModelFile(assetManager, modelFilename), options)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
```

Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

Answer (score 7):

Please check the build.gradle file for app.
If you see the below line or if the version is less than 2.3.0 update it to the latest version

**implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'**

change it to

**implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'**

it is not downloading the latest tensorflow-lite version for android.

Hope this fixes your issue